# Does Convergence of Maps Evaluated at Points Imply Convergence in Operator Norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that I have $T,T_n \in B_H$, for some Hilbert space $H$. Is the following implication true?

$$ \|(T-T_n)x\| \rightarrow 0 \ \forall x\in H \ \Rightarrow \
\|T-T_n\| \rightarrow 0, \ \text{ie} \ T_n \rightarrow T.$$

Is it valid if and only if the convergence to zero if uniform? I think I have a proof in that case, but I'm not sure:

> For an operator $A$,
>   $$\|A\| = \sup\lbrace {\|Ax\| \over \|x\|} \ | \ x \in H \rbrace = \sup\lbrace \|Ax\| \ | \ x \in B_H \rbrace
> \\ \Rightarrow
> \|T - T_n\| = \sup\lbrace \|(T-T_n)x\| \ | \ x \in B_H \rbrace \rightarrow 0,$$
>   since $\|(T-T_n)x\| \rightarrow 0$ for all $x \in H.$

Without uniform convergence, then surely we can't make the final claim, but with uniform convergence that it does seem legitimate to me.

Any help would be most appreciated - I've been stuck on this for ages!

Comment: Pointwise convergence is called Strong (operator) convergence in this setting. To see that this doesn't imply norm convergence consider the shift operator $S$ in $\ell^2$ given by $$(x_1,x_2,\ldots )\mapsto (x_2, x_3\ldots).$$ And define $T_n=S^n$ (composition).

Comment: Yes, I had thought that was the case. Thanks for the clarification. What about the uniform convergence case though?

Comment: You have the following result. $T_n\to T$ in norm if  and only if $T_n\to T$ uniformly on bounded sets.

Comment: Ah yes, I did think that that would be the case. Is my proof above right for this - well, at least, the right starting point. Obviously it would need mention of uniform convergence on bounded (probably use compact) sets.

Answer (score 1):

One should always mention the set on which uniform convergence is considered. The convergence cannot be uniform on all of $H$ unless $T_n=T$ for all large $n$.

If your assumption is that convergence is uniform on the unit ball, the proof is correct.

Or you could adopt a point of view that makes the statement tautological: the operator norm is the $C(B_H)$ norm (uniform norm on the space of continuous functions) and convergence in the uniform norm is precisely the uniform convergence.

The rest has been answered by Jose27 already:

> Pointwise convergence is called Strong (operator) convergence in this setting. To see that this doesn't imply norm convergence consider the shift operator $S$ in $\ell^2$ given by $$(x_1,x_2,\ldots )\mapsto (x_2, x_3\ldots).$$ And define $T_n=S^n$ (composition). -- [Jose27](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042745/does-convergence-of-maps-evaluated-at-points-imply-convergence-in-operator-norm#comment2124358_1042745)